# Neo4J ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError

Tags: neo4j, cypher, load-csv

I am getting **Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError** while loading data from CSV file.

> Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError: Invalid input 'h': expected
>   'i/I' (line 5, column 3 (offset: 189)) "Merge (Zip_Code:Zip_Code
>   {code: row.zip_cd,type:'location'})"

**Here is my Query:**

```
 Using Periodic Commit
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///DOL_data_whd_whisard_reduced.csv" AS row
Merge (State_Code:State_Code {code: row.st_cd})
    where not row.st_cd is null

Merge (Zip_Code:Zip_Code {code: row.zip_cd,type:'location'})
    where not row.zip_cd is null
Merge (Zip_Code)-[:located_in]->(State_Code)
```

There are some blank records in the csv and hence I have used not null but this is giving me error as:

Can anyone help me out of it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are getting an error because you are using `WHERE` with `MERGE` clause. `WHERE` can not be used with `MERGE`.

You can modify your query to remove the syntax error as follows:

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///DOL_data_whd_whisard_reduced.csv" AS row
WITH row
WHERE NOT row.st_cd IS NULL AND NOT row.zip_cd IS NULL
MERGE (state_code:State_Code {code: row.st_cd})
MERGE (zip_code:Zip_Code {code: row.zip_cd, type:'location'})
MERGE (zip_code)-[:located_in]->(state_code)
```

> **NOTE:**
>
> 1. This will skip the record if one of `st_cd`  or `zip_cd`  is NULL.
> 2. It's not recommended to use more than one `MERGE` in a single query, consider writing 3 separate queries for this.

**Recommended method:**

**Load State codes:**

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///DOL_data_whd_whisard_reduced.csv" AS row
WITH row
WHERE NOT row.st_cd IS NULL 
MERGE (state_code:State_Code {code: row.st_cd})
```

**Load Zip codes:**

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///DOL_data_whd_whisard_reduced.csv" AS row
WITH row
WHERE NOT row.zip_cd IS NULL
MERGE (zip_code:Zip_Code {code: row.zip_cd, type:'location'})
```

**Create State-Zip relationships:**

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///DOL_data_whd_whisard_reduced.csv" AS row
WITH row
WHERE NOT row.st_cd IS NULL AND NOT row.zip_cd IS NULL
MATCH (state_code:State_Code {code: row.st_cd})
MATCH (zip_code:Zip_Code {code: row.zip_cd, type:'location'})
MERGE (zip_code)-[:located_in]->(state_code)
```