# GETTING Neo.ClientError.Statement.SemanticError: Cannot merge node using null property

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

Hello I am trying to make relationship between two column in my csv file 
I am loading csv file which has an relationship column and it looks like this

```
RELATIONSHIP,AGENTID,CUSTOMERID,TXNID,TIMESTAMP,AMOUNT,CHANNEL
hasrelation,17956,2025,6C13MXSESN,2019-03-01T11:52:08,10,USSD
hasrelation,17957,2026,6C13MXSEVF,2019-03-01T11:52:09,50,BAPP
```

so I want to make relation between AGENTID and CUSTOMERID. the relationship code is

```
load csv with headers from "file:///test.csv" AS row
MERGE (p1:AGENTID {name: row.AGENTID})
MERGE (p2:CUSTOMERID {name: row.CUSTOMERID})
WITH p1, p2, row
CALL apoc.create.relationship(p1, row.relationship, {}, p2) YIELD rel
RETURN rel;
```

This is for testing purpose, but I am getting  bellow error
**Neo.ClientError.Statement.SemanticError: Cannot merge node using null property value for name**

Moreover Recently I have tried this too

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///test.csv" AS row
MATCH (f:AGENTID), (s:CUSTOMERID)
WHERE f.Name = row.AGENTID
AND s.Name = row.CUSTOMERID
CALL apoc.create.relationship(f, row.RELATIONSHIP,{}, s) YIELD rel
RETURN rel
```

I am not getting error here but I am not getting relationship result

actually I  have a feeling  that I have missed something very silly point.Kindly help me to understand why  I am getting this error. and help me to solve this problem. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting `SemanticError` for the first query because there is no value(null) for `CUSTOMERID` or `AGENTID` somewhere in your file and hence it's like you are trying to `MERGE` node on a `null` value. You need to check for null value before `MERGE` and skip `MERGE` for these. See below.

It's not recommended to use multiple `MERGE` in the single query. **Only one `MERGE` is recommended in one query.**

Suggest you separate your query into two and use your second to create relationships.

**Load AGENTIDs:**

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///test.csv" AS row
WHERE row.AGENTID IS NOT NULL
MERGE (p1:AGENTID {name: row.AGENTID});
```

**Load CUSTOMERIDs:**

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///test.csv" AS row
WHERE row.CUSTOMERID IS NOT NULL
MERGE (p2:CUSTOMERID {name: row.CUSTOMERID})
```

**Create relationships between AGENTIDs and CUSTOMERIDs:**

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///test.csv" AS row
MATCH (f:AGENTID), (s:CUSTOMERID)
WHERE f.name = row.AGENTID
AND s.name = row.CUSTOMERID
CALL apoc.create.relationship(f, row.RELATIONSHIP,{}, s) YIELD rel
RETURN rel
```

Comment: Thanks for  replying  @Raj .I have loaded file separately and MERGE  worked well. but  the third query is not working . It is not giving me error but  it is showing (no changes, no record)

Comment: oh it worked now I have just changed NAME to name :) thanks a lot . I am learning some tricks from you

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Raj for your answer. In my case it didn't work until i did some modifications. Here my new code:

**1. Load AGENTIDs:**

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///test.csv" AS row
WITH row
WHERE row.AGENTID IS NOT NULL
MERGE (p1:AGENTID {name: row.AGENTID});
```

**2. Load CUSTOMERIDs:**

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///test.csv" AS row
WITH row
WHERE row.CUSTOMERID IS NOT NULL
MERGE (p2:CUSTOMERID {name: row.CUSTOMERID})
```

**3. Create relationships between AGENTIDs and CUSTOMERIDs:**

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///test.csv" AS row
MATCH (f:AGENTID), (s:CUSTOMERID)
WHERE f.name = row.AGENTID
AND s.name = row.CUSTOMERID
CALL apoc.create.relationship(f, row.RELATIONSHIP,{}, s) YIELD rel
RETURN rel
```

Actually @Raj already mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56593300/neo4j-clienterror-statement-syntaxerror/56595594) *"WHERE can not be used with MERGE."*